# Create .ABA file inside Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I was just looking for the possibility to generate a `.aba` file inside file cabinet using suitescript. I've searched through the documents but it seems like `.aba` is not a supported file type in Netsuite. Is there any other way can we achieve this ?

Any approach or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an ABA file is just ASCII text, you could generate the file programmatically in a backend NetSuite script.

You'd pull all the various source records, convert to strings and format the ABA document, line by line.

Afterwards, you could save the file to the file system, or email it etc.